# how to install/run traceroute in gke gcp (apt not found)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, traceroute

We have google cloud composer with gke and trying to run trace route

```
Error : sudo: traceroute: command not found
-bash: traceroute: command not found
```

Through VM instances we have launched the SSH terminal and then tried traceroute commands and traceroute package is not available.

Is there any way to install traceroute and then run the commands ?

We tried with apt /sudo apt-get but no use getting

```
 error : apt not found
```

Verified `/etc/resolv.conf` as well and below is the content

nameserver 100.200.300.400
search us-north2-a.c.projectopen.internal c.projectopen.internal google.internal

Comment: What's the actual issue you are trying to debug?

Comment: I was unable to install any of the package and none of the command is working.

Comment: Oh - sorry - I meant what are you planning to use traceroute for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use SSH into a GKE node and then run `sudo toolbox` then inside the toolbox container you can install other tools such as traceroute.

You can view more details about toolbox here: https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/toolbox